# can't get the OpenGraph properties working in an iframe canvas of a Facebook app

Tags: facebook, canvas, facebook-opengraph

I can't get the opengraph properties working in an iframe canvas of a Facebook app.

I used the Facebook URL Linter to test.

What I did to slim the problem down:

1) create an HTML page (test.html) with OG properties

--> works.

2) When I 'add' this page as an iframe to another page (frame.html).

--> No OG properties found.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: here is my test: [link]http://egoactive.com/filespublic/dev/test.html and http://egoactive.com/filespublic/dev/iframe.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the solution here: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=354148#p354148
It worked for me

Comment: hmm... not for me. try http://egoactive.com/filespublic/dev/test.html versus http://egoactive.com/filespublic/dev/iframe.html or Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what are you doing with an iframe? the solution is made to work with the facebook iframe, I don't think it will work with your custom iframe. Did you try using the html file inside Facebook and it didn't read the tags?

Comment: Hi  Bogdan Bucur. The real problem I had. There is a like button within an app (in the canvas). After a like i noticed that there was no OG info on the wall. I thought it was an iframe problem.  Now fixed the problem. I had to explicit 'feed' the URL's to the facebook debugger: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug .  I had to 'feed' the URL's where the app is 'living'